# Second view not loading from xib, reference outlet set to nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a XIB file that contains multiple top-level views that don't share a parent-child relationship. One of the views corresponds to the `view` property in the file's owner, a UIViewController subclass. All of the other views are connected the view controller via reference outlets. The reference outlets are defined as strong properties in the controller.

Occasionally, in the `viewDidLoad` method in the controller, one of the views comes out to be `nil`. The strange thing is that deleting the app from the device and reinstalling it works around the problem. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

At first I suspected that maybe `viewDidLoad` does not imply that all of the views in the XIB have been loaded, rather only the main view. But I tried checking in `viewDidAppear` and there also it is nil.

Comment: Does force closing the app have any effect?  Or just removing from the device?

Comment: Nope. Force closing doesn't help. The problem only occurs when an existing version is updated to the latest build.